# How to save user inputs in a list?-Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a mathematics game which asks a random question from a set list. I want to be able to save user inputs in a new list so i can display their answers at the end of the game.
Can anybody help me figure out how to do this?

```
import random
counter = 0
score = 0
incorrect = 0

name=input("What is your name?")
print("Hi",name,",welcome to your math quiz!")

questions = ["10*2","4-2","6+12","6*4","12-5","6+54","1*0","3-6","4+0","65-9"]
answers=["20","2","18","24",'7','60','0','-3','4','56']

idx_questions = list(enumerate(questions))
idx_answers = list(enumerate(answers))

random.shuffle(idx_questions)

for idxq, question in idx_questions:
    print(question)
    ans = input("What is the answer? ")
    for idxa, answer in idx_answers:
        if idxq == idxa and ans == answer:
            print("Correct")
            score=score+1
            print("Correct Answers=",score)
            print("Incorrect Answers=",incorrect)

        elif idxq == idxa and ans != answer:
            print("Incorrect", answers)
            incorrect=incorrect+1
            print("Correct Answers=",score)
            print("Incorrect Answers=",incorrect)

print("End of quiz")
print(name,"your score is",score,"out of 10")
print(score*10,"%")
```

Comment: You should probably read [ask] and edit your question a bit.

Comment: At the beginning of the game, instantiate an empty list `youranswers = []` then for each answer just append it to the list when you get it `youranswers.append(ans)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
inputs = []
for idxq, question in idx_questions:
    print(question)
    ans = input("What is the answer? ")
    inputs.append(ans)
    for idxa, answer in idx_answers:
        # ...
```